# apache caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

Tags: python, php, apache, ffmpeg

I need your help please.
This is what happening: I'm trying to generate a video thanks to ffmpeg.
To do so I have a directory where I put the medias (video and images) I want to put on my final video.
Then once my files ready to be used (right bitrate, resolution, and so on...), I call a python script that generates the ffmpeg code to produce my video.

The python script is called from my php script with the escapeshellcmd command.

Problem is my apache server keeps crashing each time I try to produce a video.

In the error log I see this:
[mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 745] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully

Could someone help or give me hint please?

Thanks a lot,
Damien